# Pandas shift index ignoring passed shift object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Let's say I've df like this

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.date_range('2023-04-01', '2023-05-01')
frequency = df.shift(freq='W')
print(frequency)
```

output I got freuqnecy as `None`

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-04-02', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-09',
               '2023-04-09', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-09',
               '2023-04-16', '2023-04-16', '2023-04-16', '2023-04-16',
               '2023-04-16', '2023-04-16', '2023-04-16', '2023-04-23',
               '2023-04-23', '2023-04-23', '2023-04-23', '2023-04-23',
               '2023-04-23', '2023-04-23', '2023-04-30', '2023-04-30',
               '2023-04-30', '2023-04-30', '2023-04-30', '2023-04-30',
               '2023-04-30', '2023-05-07', '2023-05-07'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None) <<<<<<<<--------Here------<<<<<
```

According to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.9.1/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) `W` stands for week

Am i missing anything here?? I was looking for a quick fix..Is there any alternate way to do it?

```
Version: 1.4.2
```

[image]

Comment: Oh that is interesting... why did the freq go away?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but it gives you the expected outcome.

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.shift.html):

```
month_starts = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5, freq='MS')
month_starts
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01', '2011-02-01', '2011-03-01', '2011-04-01',
               '2011-05-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
month_starts.shift(10, freq='D')
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-11', '2011-02-11', '2011-03-11', '2011-04-11',
               '2011-05-11'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

It produces the right outcome.

In your case the original `df`:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-03', '2023-04-04',
               '2023-04-05', '2023-04-06', '2023-04-07', '2023-04-08',
               '2023-04-09', '2023-04-10', '2023-04-11', '2023-04-12',
               '2023-04-13', '2023-04-14', '2023-04-15', '2023-04-16',
               '2023-04-17', '2023-04-18', '2023-04-19', '2023-04-20',
               '2023-04-21', '2023-04-22', '2023-04-23', '2023-04-24',
               '2023-04-25', '2023-04-26', '2023-04-27', '2023-04-28',
               '2023-04-29', '2023-04-30', '2023-05-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

is converting to the next week (always the sunday of the week):

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-04-02', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-09',
               '2023-04-09', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-09',
               '2023-04-16', '2023-04-16', '2023-04-16', '2023-04-16',
               '2023-04-16', '2023-04-16', '2023-04-16', '2023-04-23',
               '2023-04-23', '2023-04-23', '2023-04-23', '2023-04-23',
               '2023-04-23', '2023-04-23', '2023-04-30', '2023-04-30',
               '2023-04-30', '2023-04-30', '2023-04-30', '2023-04-30',
               '2023-04-30', '2023-05-07', '2023-05-07'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

He gives back the frequency none because the datapoints don't have a frequency. You could clean the "duplicates" and then you have your preferred frequency:

```
print(frequency.drop_duplicates())
DatetimeIndex(['2023-04-02', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-16', '2023-04-23',
               '2023-04-30', '2023-05-07'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

but it will not detect the frequency then.

Comment: one week logically 7D ...so setting freq to 7D also worked for me :)